# ggvis add_tooltip is not working with layer_bars

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have the following code that I am trying to build into the shiny dashboard. If I change to layer_point the code works.

I tried to change to layer_rect instead - however, I am unable to get a stacked bar chart with layer rects.

I have attached a photo below error.

[image]

```
color_choices <- c("#08519C","#238B45")

tab2_1 %>%  
  ungroup() %>%
  ggvis(x=~variable, y=~value, fill = ~Tender_won) %>%
  layer_bars() %>% 
  add_axis("y",title="Volume",title_offset=80) %>%
  add_axis("x",title ="Year") %>%
  scale_ordinal("fill",range = color_choices) %>%
  add_tooltip(function(data) paste0("test1",data$value,"test2")) %>%
  add_legend(scales = "fill", values = c("No","Yes"), title = "Tender Status")
```

The Data can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3lq6qncru0xuvoc/helphelp.csv?dl=0

Comment: have your tried layer_rects? And it's not clear in your question what's not working, layer_bars or layer_rects. I have tried both and it's working

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply - i have tried layer rects, but it does an overlay instead of stacking it up.

and the problem is with this dataset, if i tried the examples from mtcars or iris, it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll use the `hec` example from the `compute_stack` documentation to show you some examples of how to add tooltips to a stacked bar plot.  The exact nature of the tooltip will depend on which data you want the tooltip to display.  My guess is you want to display the length of each stacked bar section (the actual y value from the original dataset).

It helps me to know what the dataset looked like that `layer_bars` used for graphing.  You can see this by using `compute_stack` directly and looking at the resulting dataset.

```
hec = as.data.frame(xtabs(Freq ~ Hair + Eye, HairEyeColor))
hec %>% compute_stack(~Freq, ~Hair)

Source: local data frame [16 x 6]

     Hair    Eye  Freq group__ stack_upr_ stack_lwr_
   (fctr) (fctr) (dbl)  (fctr)      (dbl)      (dbl)
1   Black  Brown    68   Black         68          0
2   Brown  Brown   119   Brown        119          0
3     Red  Brown    26     Red         26          0
4   Blond  Brown     7   Blond          7          0
5   Black   Blue    20   Black         88         68
6   Brown   Blue    84   Brown        203        119
7     Red   Blue    17     Red         43         26
8   Blond   Blue    94   Blond        101          7
9   Black  Hazel    15   Black        103         88
10  Brown  Hazel    54   Brown        257        203
11    Red  Hazel    14     Red         57         43
12  Blond  Hazel    10   Blond        111        101
13  Black  Green     5   Black        108        103
14  Brown  Green    29   Brown        286        257
15    Red  Green    14     Red         71         57
16  Blond  Green    16   Blond        127        111
```

Notice the upper and lower y coordinates used in plotting each section of each bar are called `stack_upr_` and `stack_lwr_`.  While these values are based on the original y variable `Freq`, the `Freq` values aren't directly plotted.  I think this may be what tripped you up.

Based on this info, if you want a tooltip to show the original y value you can simply subtract the lower y coordinate of each stack from the upper y coordinate within your tooltip.

```
hec %>% ggvis(x = ~Hair, y = ~Freq, fill = ~Eye) %>%
    layer_bars() %>%
    add_tooltip(function(data) paste0("test1 ", data$stack_upr_ - data$stack_lwr_, " test2"))
```

Comment: Hi! thank you so much for your response and apologies for my late reply.

i understand why it causes this error, and is able to put the value - however, what if i want to show the percentage instead of the value? taking data$stack_lwr_ / data$stack_upr_ will not work, any suggested work around?

Comment: Ok, i can overcome this error by adding a customize function, but this would not work in a shiny environment as my data frame would be an reactive object. this is quite unfortunate.... 

But now i have a better understanding of how the tool tips works and their limitations! thank you so much!